# Parallelize integration tests with pytest-xdist

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, pytest

I was wondering if it is possible to use an in memory SQLite database to perform integration tests in parallel using pytest and pytrest-xdist on a FastAPI application?

**Update**

I have a good number of tests that I would like to run during my CI (GitLab CI), however, due to the number of IOPS that need to be executed for each test when using a file for SQLite the job times out so I would like to use an in-memory database, as well as parallelize the tests using pytest-xdist.

Every endpoint uses FastAPI's dependency injection for the db context, and what I have tried is to create a fixture for the app as so:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def app():
    """
    Pytest fixture that creates an instance of the FastAPI application.
    """
    app = create_app()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db

    return app
```

```py
def override_get_db():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"sqlite:///:memory:"

    engine = create_engine(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
    )
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    TestLocalSession = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    init_db(session=TestLocalSession)
    engine.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
    try:
        db = TestLocalSession()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Because the endpoints are all sync I also need to use httpx instead of the built in TestClient:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
async def client(app):
    """
    Pytest fixture that creates an instance of the Flask test client.
    """
    async with AsyncClient(
        app=app, base_url=f"{settings.BASE_URL}{settings.API_PREFIX}"
    ) as client:
        yield client
```

The issue I have when I run this test (without pytest-xdist) is that the database is being created in a seperate thread as that which is being injected into the endpoints so I always get a SQL error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: certification`

Any suggestion on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: sure you can... do you have a specific question in mind? see the guide to [ask]

Comment: @MichaelDelgado sorry I could not find information on this particular task so I was not sure if it was possible. I updated my ticket with what I have tried and the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you might just be dealing with a race condition? You might be able to deal with this by setting up the database within the `pytest_configure` as in this example: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/783. Or you could just set up the database before calling pytest and then tear it down manually.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thank you so much! That (plus some minor changes) fixed it and made my tests so much faster that now i can actually run  them in my CI system :)